# Install asp.net nightly build with nuget

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, nuget-package

I'm trying to install the nighlty build version of asp.net as described here
http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Use%20Nightly%20Builds
I want to use the nightly build in order to use the ODataController to add OData support.

I have added http://www.myget.org/F/aspnetwebstacknightly/ to my package source list
I am not sure what nuget command i should use in order to install the nightly build

I have tried following commands but i'm pretty sure i'm missing the point here somewhere.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet -version "nightly 2013 Feb 14"
Install-Package AspNet -version "nightly 2013 Feb 14"
Install-Package AspNet
Install-Package Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi -version "nightly 2013 Feb 14"
```

What command do i need in order to install the latest version of asp.net in order to support ODataController, i'm using VS2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like they released yesterday! so i no longer need to use ( or attempt to use) the nightly build

https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData